# Adding functions dynamically to function.prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a newbie to nodejs.
I am writing a helper function to build JSON using a schema, I am trying to add functions (mostly setters) to set values. The following is a simple version of it.

```
function Task() {
  this.action = {};
  this.schedule = {};
}

function capitalize(str) {
  return `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1)}`;
}

const scheduleProps = [
'startAt',
'repeatEvery',
'endAt',
'count',
'interval'
];
```

Add methods to it dynamically

```
for(var i=0; i<scheduleProps.length; i++) {
  Object.defineProperty(Task.prototype, `set${capitalize(scheduleProps[i])}`, {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: (value) => {
      this.schedule[scheduleProps[i]] = value;
    }
  });
}
```

When I call the following way I expect obj.schedule.repeatEvery to contain value 10.

```
obj = new Task();
obj.setRepeatEvery(10);
```

Instead I get

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'repeatEvery' of undefined
```

I even tried to set the functions like so

```
  Task.prototype[`set${capitalize(scheduleProps[i])}`] = (val) => {
    this.schedule[scheduleProps[i]] = val;
  }
```

In this case I get

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'interval' of undefined
at Task.(anonymous function) [as setRepeatEvery]
```

How can I set methods to a function.prototype dynamically? 
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Where is the loop run? Lambda (arrow) functions won't have the correct `this` scope if that loop doesn't run inside a member method. try using a regular `function`

Comment: Awesome Balázs!! I had to move it into the constructor and it worked. I need to have them as lambda function in order to set the functions to the main function prototype

Comment: JSON is a data exchange format, like XML or YAML. I don't see any JSON in your example. JavaScript objects are not JSON.

Comment: Another question I had was which of the methods is better? Is defining by `Object.defineProperty()` prefered over `Task.prototype[methodName] `?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Can you show what you want the prototype to look like after you add these dynamic things to it?  And, then how you want to access things.  For starters, your `for` loop has already run to completion so your `i` variable is wrong when your value method gets called.

Comment: @GuruGovindan great, glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were facing that **issue** mainly because of **function assignment for "value" key**.

You can find **some changes** there which is creating **a closure** and also changed the **syntax of assigning a function** at key of an object.

**Closure** is created to maintain the value of i for that particular iteration.

```js
function Task() {
  this.action = {};
  this.schedule = {};
}

function capitalize(str) {
  return `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1)}`;
}

const scheduleProps = [
    'startAt',
    'repeatEvery',
    'endAt',
    'count',
    'interval'
];

for(var i=0; i<scheduleProps.length; i++) {
  Object.defineProperty(Task.prototype, `set${capitalize(scheduleProps[i])}`, {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: (function(i) { return function(value) { this.schedule[scheduleProps[i]] = value;} })(i)
  });
}

obj = new Task();
obj.setRepeatEvery(10);
```

Comment: Thanks Jitendra, I had to move the for loop into the Task() constructor. By  adding anonymous function the **this** is the scope of the anonymous funciton. I wanted the methods to be added to the Task.prototype

Comment: By above code those functions are already on prototype of Task Class. You can run this code in Browser console and after that type "Task.prototype." this will shows you all there.

Comment: An answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how to fix it.

Comment: @RobG Thanks. Added Explanation for the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jitendra. As you had mentioned I was missing the array scope when the function was actually executing. Awesome.. !